# Iterating a SharePoint 2010 Atom feed

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

SharePoint 2010 returns an Atom feed when using its REST API.

For example:

```
http://SERVER/Tasks/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Tasks?$select=Id,Title,Status&$filter=UserId eq 1234&$orderby=Status asc
```

Results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://SERVER/Tasks/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">Tasks</title>
  <id>http://SERVER/Tasks/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Tasks</id>
  <updated>2015-04-23T19:03:12Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="Tasks" href="Tasks" />
  <entry m:etag="W/&quot;22&quot;">
    <id>http://SERVER/Tasks/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Tasks(4444)</id>
    <title type="text">Lorem Ipsum</title>
    <updated>2015-04-20T00:00:00-00:00</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="List" href="Tasks(4444)" />
    <category term="Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.TasksItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Title>Lorem Ipsum</d:Title>
        <d:Status>Complete</d:Status>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">4444</d:Id>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  ...
</feed>
```

I'm hoping to list each `<m:property>` element as a row in Format-Table, but this code doesn't work:

```
...
[xml]$xml = Get-Url $url
$xml.feed.entry.content.properties | Format-Table -Property @{Label="Id"; Expression={$_.Id."#text"}},
      @{Label="Title"; Expression={$_.Title}},
      @{Label="Status"; Expression={$_.Status}}
```

I suspect this relates to the namespaces, but I'm not sure why.  It would seem that PowerShell would be aware of this, given that it has already parse the XML.

In general, is there an easier way to work with Atom feeds?

** edit 0 **

Fixed name of `Status` field.

Would expect to see something like this:

```
Id         Title      Status
---------- ---------- ----------
8345       Lorem ipsu Active
4534       Ipsum lore Inactive
...
```

Instead, nothing is returned (no column header, no rows).

** edit 1 **

```
function Get-Url {

    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
      [String] $webUrl
    ) 

    begin { Write-Verbose "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)::Begin" }

    process {

        try {

            $req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($webUrl)        
            $req.Method ="GET"
            # JSON
            # $req.Accept = "application/json; odata=verbose"
            # $req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            $req.ContentLength = 0
            $req.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials

            $resp = $req.GetResponse()
            $reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($resp.GetResponseStream())

            return $reader.ReadToEnd()  

        }
        catch [Exception] {
            Write-Host $_.Exception.ToString()
        }
        finally {
            if ($reader -ne $null) {
                $reader.Close()
            }
        }

    }

    end { Write-Verbose "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)::End" }

}
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what does that mean exactly? I ran it and it seems to work.

Comment: I didn't get any errors, but it doesn't return the results that I would expect.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what you expect. I got the Id and the Title. I didn't get the status, but for some reason you're using `$_.RequestStatusValue` instead of `$_.Status`.

Comment: Could you share Get-Url function?